# How return only one column as output in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to return only one column as output in MySQL.

This works:

```
select COALESCE(sum(debit_amt),0) as credit from client_debit_bal where mob_no=id
```

but when I try the following query it does not:

```
select COALESCE(sum(debit_amt),0) as credit from client_debit_bal where mob_no=id 
and cmy_code='001'
```

I only need `credit` to be outputted. What am I missing?

Comment: `its not working ` - what does it mean?

Comment: Your query would only return one column as written. Do you mean only one **row**?

Comment: When i use two more condition the query is not working... The second query is not working..

Comment: correct. only one column as written.

Comment: @DineshG, `is not working` -- Your screen starts to blink or what?

Comment: FIrst try to work your `Select query` to output all, after than you can use the `LIMIT.`

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  "Not working" is not very specific.

Comment: Actually No result found...

Comment: You have no record that satisfies the conditions. Add that record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for `LIMIT`?

`LIMIT` clause constrains the number of result.

You can fetch the first N rows using `LIMIT [N]`.

Suppose there is a table like following,

```
tbl_t

| idx | name  | age | 
| 0   | Tom   | 30  |
| 1   | Jerry | 25  |
| 2   | Bob   | 30  |
| 3   | Ken   | 45  |
```

Then query following statement,

`SELECT name FROM tbl_t WHERE age=30`

result would be {'Tom', 'Bob'}.

But if you query `SELECT name FROM tbl_t WHERE age=30 LIMIT 1` then
result would be {'Tom'}.

If you want to get further information, visit http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx .

Comment: this looks like for comment post only. Although it might solve the problem. try to give the op a sample working query rathen than only link or explanation from that link.

Comment: @Niang Thank you for your comment. I cannot comment on the question because my reputation is under 50, but I'll add some sample code, though.

Comment: @ishez haha sorry, but try to edit your post and add the example, because if you only provide the link, and if the link is not working in the future, your link cant help.

Comment: @ishez If you cannot comment, then DON'T comment.  Abusing the system by posting comments as answers will only make it harder for you to achieve the rep necessary to be able to comment.  Don't abuse the system.

Comment: @JimGarrison I want to say that I don't have an intention to abuse the system, sorry. I've got your point. Simple answers should be commented and should not be posted. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it's only questions to the original poster asking for clarification that should be comments.  If the original question is clear enough to answer, you should answer regardless of how simple.  It's only when the original question is unclear that you need to comment to ask for clarification.  Posting a guess as an answer is usually a bad idea unless you are 99% certain you've guessed right. In this case it's not at all clear that LIMIT is what the OP needs.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you for letting me know the detail. As a non-native English speaker and a member who recently started to answer, I learned a lot from you.